# Read a dng file as a 2d array of pixels in android

Tags: android, image-processing, camera2

I have a DNG file that my camera2 application generates. I want to read that file as a part of another android application and process the values at a pixel level. I haven't found a way to read the same. Are there any approaches I can use?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in API in Android to read in full-resolution DNG files (As of Android N, you can read in DNG thumbnails via some new APIs).

Your primary options are to use Adobe's [DNG SDK](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/dng/dng_sdk.html), or use one of the open-source libraries such as [libraw](http://www.libraw.org/).  I don't know if any of these have a Java interface.